# Strange issue with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed Python 3.7.4, and then jupyter using pip.

On running command, 'jupyter notebook' from windows cmd, I get message as:

> [C 17:47:19.194 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
>   [C 17:47:19.194 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: ''C:\work\ml\work\notebooks''

'C:\work\ml\work\notebooks' is a folder path in my computer'. But what has jupyter anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter notebook renders a page showing the directory structure which you might or might not had mentioned it during the installation. Also your location might not exist.

Use jupyter notebook config file:
Open cmd 
run jupyter notebook --generate-config.

A fike is created at C:\Users\username.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py.

Open the above file in editor

Search for the following line in the file: #c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''

Replace by c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/the/path/to/home/folder/'

Make sure you use forward slashes in your path and use /home/user/ instead of ~/ for your home directory, backslashes could be used if placed in double quotes even if folder name contains spaces as such : "D:\yourUserName\Any Folder\More Folders\"

Remove the # at the beginning of the line to allow the line to execute